# Problems with varnish and apache (trying to improve OpenCart)

Tags: apache, caching, varnish

I'm trying to give my webshop a boost with warnish.
Setup varnish port 80, backend is 127.0.0.1 apache2.

Apache Benchmark gives awefull resulst, like 1-2 request/sec !

On the very first displayed file; header.tpl I have :

```
<?php
  cache_control( "public, s-max-age=6000");
  expires( to_gmt( time() + 6000 ) );
?>
```

Below is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 151613
Expires: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 20:04:07
Cache-Control: public, s-max-age=6000
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=i9h5ldj8k4fking69d03jr5244; path=/, language=en; expires=Thu, 28-Mar-2013 18:24:06 GMT; path=/; domain=www.domain.com, currency=CHF; expires=Thu, 28-Mar-2013 18:24:06 GMT; path=/; domain=www.domain.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 18:24:07 GMT
X-Varnish: 186646239
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Cache: MISS
```

Must be missing something obvious but to me varnish just doesn't cache; what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: If you listen to the uncached PHP response, is `Pragma: no-cache` present there too?

Comment: Believe me I've tried, its IMPOSSIBLE to improve opencart. Also depends a lot on the developer, but I'd actually go for magento or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP most likely has [`session.cache-limiter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter) set to `nocache` (the default).

This would send a `Pragma: no-cache` (and as far as I understand an Expire header set to the current time) to Varnish and thus disabling caching.

Comment: Ok; i've put 'session_cache_limiter('public');' very first line; still getting the no-cache

Comment: changed in php.ini; now pragma:nocache is gone, now public; but still poor performance, nothing improved.

Comment: Maybe something with : Age:0 ?

Comment: @Disco No, `Age: 0` means that it hasn't been cached though, it means that Varnish says the page it's service has been cached for 0 seconds.

Comment: Ok, seems that it's not possible to use varnish at all with opencart since it starts session on each page; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766729/varnish-cache-shopping-carts

Answer (score 0):

Varnish will ignore the « Pragma : no-cache » by default, unless it is instruction to handle the directive (https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html).

Your cache-control seems to be configuring properly and should be cached for 6000 second.
The next things that you need to take into consideration are the cookie. Looking in your header, you have a PHP session Cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=i9h5ldj8k4fking69d03jr5244;
```

Varnish will not cache the cookie unless you remove it the request in your vcl file. Ex :

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID =[^;]+(; )?", "");
}
```